# jmeter - how to skip specific row from csv

Tags: csv, jmeter

I've a csv like this:

```
NAME;F1;F2;
test1;field1;field2
test2;field1;field2
test3;field1;field2
```

I would test only test1, so I would change the csv in

```
ID;F1;F2;
test1;field1;field2
#test2;field1;field2
#test3;field1;field2
```

how can I skip rows of test2 and test3 in jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a way to do to something.. 
maybe my way is not the best and "pretty" but it worth!

- Thread Group

  - Loop Controller

    - csv Data Set Config
    - if Controller

      - Http Request

Inside If Controller I added this code:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('ID').take(1)!='#')}
```

In this way when you put an # at the start of the row it will be skipped.

I hope it could be helpfull for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, the only option I can think of is creating a new CSV file out of the existing one with just first 2 lines like:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   new File('original.csv').readLines().take(2).each {line ->
       new File('new.csv') << line << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   }
   ```

   Replace `original.csv` with path to the current CSV file and set up CSV Data Set Config to use `new.csv`
4. The above code will write first 2 lines from the `original.csv` into the `new.csv` so you will be able to access limited external data instead of the full CSV file.

More information:

- [File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines())
- [Collection.take()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#take-java.lang.Iterable-int-)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: that's what I'm actually doing.. I hope there was a simple way to do something .. if (row  ==~ "^#" ) { skip} ..